# (android.content.Context, android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView)' in 'com.joyfm96.joy.EntertainmentFragment' cannot be applied to '()'

Tags: java, android

am building an app that pull rss feed from a website using a tablayout but  i have a broplem this the error am getting:

'BusinessFragment(android.content.Context, android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView)' in 'com.joyfm96.joy.BusinessFragment' cannot be applied to '()'

this is my TabFragment.java

```
package com.joyfm96.joy;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;


import com.joyfm96.joy.R;

public class TabFragment extends Fragment {

    public static TabLayout tabLayout;
    public static ViewPager viewPager;
    public static int int_items = 4 ;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_layout, container, false);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));

        tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
            }
        });

        return v;

    }

    class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position)
        {
            switch (position){
                case 0 : return new EntertainmentFragment();
                case 1 : return new PoliticsFragment();
                case 2 : return new BusinessFragment();
                case 3 : return new SportsFragment();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return int_items;

        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

            switch (position){
                case 0 :
                    return getResources().getString(R.string.tab1);
                case 1 :
                    return getResources().getString(R.string.tab2);
                case 2 :
                    return getResources().getString(R.string.tab3);
                case 3 :
                    return getResources().getString(R.string.tab4);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

and this is the EntertainmentFragment.java

```
package com.joyfm96.joy;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

public class EntertainmentFragment extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    Context context;
    String address = "http://joyfm96.com/category/entertainment/feed/";
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    ArrayList<FeedItem>feedItems;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    URL url;
    public EntertainmentFragment(Context context,RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        this.recyclerView=recyclerView;
        this.context = context;
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        MyAdapter adapter=new MyAdapter(context,feedItems);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new VerticalSpace(50));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ProcessXml(Getdata());

        return null;
    }

    private void ProcessXml(Document data) {
        if (data != null) {
            feedItems=new ArrayList<>();
            Element root = data.getDocumentElement();
            Node channel = root.getChildNodes().item(1);
            NodeList items = channel.getChildNodes();
            for (int i = 0; i < items.getLength(); i++) {
                Node cureentchild = items.item(i);
                if (cureentchild.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                    FeedItem item=new FeedItem();
                    NodeList itemchilds = cureentchild.getChildNodes();
                    for (int j = 0; j < itemchilds.getLength(); j++) {
                        Node cureent = itemchilds.item(j);
                        if (cureent.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")){
                            item.setTitle(cureent.getTextContent());
                        }else if (cureent.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("description")){
                            item.setDescription(cureent.getTextContent());
                        }else if (cureent.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("pubDate")){
                            item.setPubDate(cureent.getTextContent());
                        }else if (cureent.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("link")){
                            item.setLink(cureent.getTextContent());
                        }else if (cureent.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("media:thumbnail")){
                            //this will return us thumbnail url
                            String url=cureent.getAttributes().item(0).getTextContent();
                            item.setThumbnailUrl(url);
                        }
                    }
                    feedItems.add(item);





                }
            }
        }
    }

    public Document Getdata() {
        try {
            url = new URL(address);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document xmlDoc = builder.parse(inputStream);
            return xmlDoc;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

how do i fix this error??
thanks

Comment: add "BusinessFragment" class

Comment: BusinessFragment Class is already there but the error still shows under the tablayout. please look at the code again and see

Answer (score 0):

From the log it looks like you are trying to create object with default constructor, but there is no default constructor in your class file for which you are creating object  in tab.

Add default constructor to those files or while creating object in Tab class use the one that are present in BusinesFragment, EmployeeFragment, etc